# Erlang Common Test syntax highlighting on the console?

Tags: terminal, erlang, syntax-highlighting, common-test

Is there a way to get syntax hightlighting on the test results that Common Test prints to the console? I am coming from a Ruby background and I like the way Rspec highlights failed and successful messages differently. Is there an option for this in CT?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `rebar ct` to run your suites? I wrote a replacement: https://github.com/rlipscombe/topcat

It has syntax highlighting, to a point. You might find it useful; you might not.

Comment: I am currently using erlang.mk but I will check it out. I have a feeling Common Test doesn't have support for any type of syntax highlighting.

Comment: It'll probably work with erlang.mk as well; it's a replacement for `rebar ct`, rather than the whole of `rebar`.